# Google App Engine Boilerplate "access was denied to this resource" error after trying to upload form

Tags: python, google-app-engine, python-2.7

I have a website and I want to allow admins to upload pictures through an upload form.

**HTML**: On a page `blob.html`:

```
<form name="uploader" action="/blob/" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file"><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Upload">
</form>
```

**blob.py**:

```
import os

import webapp2
import jinja2    

# blobstore api
from google.appengine.ext import blobstore
from google.appengine.ext.webapp import blobstore_handlers

template_env = jinja2.Environment(loader=jinja2.FileSystemLoader(os.getcwd()))

class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler): 

    def get(self):

        upload_url = blobstore.create_upload_url('/blob/')
        template = template_env.get_template('blob.html') 
        context = {
             'upload_url': upload_url
        }
        self.response.write(template.render(context))

    def post(self):

        upload_files = self.get_uploads('uploader')
        blob_info = upload_files[0]
        # So some logging here and concept to store the reference of the blob key.
        #self.redirect('/')
```

**app.yaml**:

```
...stuff...
handlers:
- url: /blob/
  script: blob.app
  login: admin

...stuff...
```

But when I go to the `/blob/` on my website, I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 239, in Handle
    handler = _config_handle.add_wsgi_middleware(self._LoadHandler())
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 301, in _LoadHandler
    raise err
ImportError: <module 'blob' from '/base/data/home/apps/s~themoringathebetter/1.372284039078482061/blob.pyc'> has no attribute app
```

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried under the `post` method, instead of saying "This is where I'm stuck"? Code, whether its broken or not is helpful.

Comment: Please don't totaly edit the question. Open a new one. You have 2 mistakes. 1. `create_upload_url` should be `create_upload_url(/blob/)`. 2. Show us your app.yaml there you need to define the route. 3. You don't pass the upload_url string to the template. You need to do that.

Comment: You get the error because probably your app.yaml does not know about the route.

Comment: also check updated answer.

Comment: @JimmyKane Okay, I updated my question for the current code. Now, I'm getting a log error. One thing that's interesting to me is it says `blob` has no extension `app`. When I switch it to `.py` it says the CGI script can't handle it.

Comment: @JaceCotton add to `blob.py` at the end the handler for your route...

`app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
        ("/blob/", MainPage)
    ],debug=True)`

Comment: @JaceCotton and name it blob.app!!!!!

Comment: @JaceCotton also this is not a good way to go creating apps for every route but i hope you'll catch up in the way.

Comment: @JimmyKane Man, just wanna say thanks for your help and patience. But, when I hit "Submit," I get this error: `Internal Server Error: AttributeError: 'MainPage' object has no attribute 'get_uploads'` Since in the class of `MainPage` it's referencing itself saying `self.get_uploads()` I put the line of code you gave me earlier *above* the class definition, seeing if it works now.

Comment: Agh. Of course, `MainPage` isn't defined if I put it there before.

Comment: And now? This is why I told you to start with a single routing example and then reach the point of post/get and then go to images. You start to develop vice versa. It will only waste your time.

Comment: @JaceCotton and dont use 'uploader' or names that are not needed. Use upload on `self.get_uploads('upload')`

Comment: @JimmyKane Oh, I thought `self.get_uploads` needed the name of my HTML form? Not the case? And now it's saying "list index is out of range." And also, this seems to be a popular parameter to pass in the `MainPage` class `blobstore_handlers.BlobstoreUploadHandler` Do we need this?

Comment: @JaceCotton Why access it as an array? do a `logging.info(upload_files)` to see what it is and handle it. You probable going to have a blob entity. It's not an array

Comment: @JimmyKane it's still saying `'MainPage' object has no attribute 'get_uploads'`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43071/discussion-between-jimmy-kane-and-jace-cotton)

Comment: once more updated the answer

Comment: @JaceCotton did a full rewrite of my answer to give a link to an app I made that you can run and get the image.

Comment: Did you try removing all pyc files? Those sometimes cause this kind of trouble when the py file in a project has been deleted, but the matching pyc file hasn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Full rewrite

So practically you **want someone to code** a small boilerplate for you, here you are.
Use `/uploadform/` for the form and `/` for the index. I kept is as simple as I could.

[BoilerPlate Form for image uploads](https://github.com/jimmykane/gae-image-upload-example)

Make sure you have [PIL](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/images/installingPIL) installed. (Tip: For osx use easy_install pil)

Comment: @JaceCotton Edited some mistakes. I I replaced varaible names to your needs.

Comment: @JaceCotton Edited the code to POST on `/` . You need to setup your routes and how your app will handle them. Since now you use only `/` it's ok, but read https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig about urls and https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstartedpython27/usingwebapp

Comment: But my actual home page uses `/` and I'd prefer to keep it that way. Why can't it use a new page, such as `upload`?

Comment: Keep it as you like noone says otherwise. You can use but read the docs on hot to handle "register" the route to the application. @JaceCotton

Comment: Thanks for your help, and I sincerely apologize for all the trouble, but the code does not work. If I go to `/upload` it returns an error of "blob.html", and if I even try to go back to the homepage it returns an error `uri_for` is not defined. If I change it back, however, the homepage error goes away. Anyways, thanks again. I'll try to figure it out with what you gave me.

Comment: Check my edited code please. Don't need to use upload. There is no reference of it and read the doc please. Don try and fail when learning. Read, sleep in it etc...

Comment: you can't render the template `blob.html` on the route of `/` because that's what my homepage already does.

Comment: Then route it elsewhere I am not going to write the code for you... Create another handler, route `/upload` there correct the given code etc

Comment: Thank you soo much, this was a big help. Sorry it came down to writing a whooole boilerplate app. :P Anyways, I really appreciate it. :)

Comment: @JaceCotton Np. I had the same problems with you at start and now recoding it. Take care.